# Higher Order Component in DOM to Wrap functionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-functions

I need to wrap functionality in a, lets say button. However when I call the HOC in the render method of another component I get nothing.

I have this HOC

```
import React,{Component,PropTypes} from 'react';

export let AddComment = (ComposedComponent) => class AC extends React.Component  {


        render() {
            return (
                <div class="something">
                    Something...
                    <ComposedComponent {...this.props}/>
                </div>
            );
        }


}
```

and trying to do this

```
import {AddComment} from '../comments/add.jsx';
var Review = React.createClass({

render: function(){
    return (
            <div className="container">
{AddComment(<button>Add Comment</button>,this.props)}
</div>
});
module.exports = Review;
```

I want AddComment to open a Dialog and submit a comments form when I click the button. I need AddComment to be available other components throughtout the app.

Is the HOC pattern correct? How can I easily accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**To summarize really quick: What are higher-order components?**

> Just a fancy name for a simple concept: Simply put: A component that takes in a component and returns you back a more enhanced version of
>   the component.

- We are essentially enhancing a component.

  - Accepts a function that maps owner props to a new collection of props
    that are passed to the base component.
  - We are basically passing the props down from that BaseComponent down 
    to the Wrapped Component so that we can have them available in that
    child component below:

  > Use to compose multiple higher-order components into a single
  >   higher-order component.

  ```
  import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import { AddComment } from '../comments/add.jsx';

  const mapProps = propFunction => Component => (props) => {
   return React.createFactory(Component)(propFunction(props));
  };

  const compose = (propFunction, ComponentContainer) => (BaseComponent) => {
      return propFunction(ComponentContainer(BaseComponent));
  };

  const Review = AddComment(({ handleReviewToggle }) => (
      <div className="container">
        <ReviewButton
          primaryText="Add Comment"
          _onClick={handleReviewToggle}
        />
      </div>
    ));

  export default Review;
  ```

// ================================================================== //

```
  const EnhanceReview = compose(withProps, AddComment)(Review);

  const withProps = mapProps(({ ...props }) => ({ ...props }));
```

The AddComment Container that will have the button and the dialog itself.

```
  export function AddComment(ComposedComponent) {
    class AC extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();

      this.state = {open: false};
    }

    handleReviewToggle = () => {
      this.setState({ open: !this.state.open })
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <ComposedComponent
          {...this.props}
          {...this.state}
          {...{
            handleReviewToggle: this.handleReviewToggle,
          }}
        />
      );
    }
  }

  export default AddComment;
```

// ==================================================================

The ReviewButton Button that will fire an event to change state true or false.

```
  const ReviewButton = ({ _onClick, primaryText }) => {
    return (
      <Button
        onClick={_onClick}
      >
        {primaryText || 'Default Text'}
      </Button>
    );
  };

  export default ReviewButton;
```

// ================================================================== //

However this was all done without using a library. There's one out called `recompose` here: https://github.com/acdlite/recompose. I highly suggest that you try it out without a library to get a good understanding of Higher Order Components.

You should be able to answer these questions below after playing with Higher Order components:

1. What is a Higher Order Component?
2. What are the disadvantages of using `HOC`? What are some use cases?
3. How will this improve performance? And how can I use this to optimize for performance?
4. When is the right time to use a HOC?